# MYSQL nested select query with *

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, nested

I have a table called incidents and it has the following fields:

```
`index`, `timestamp`, `refNum`, `priority`, `status`, `type`, `email`, `telephone`, `title`, `description`, `system`, `category`, `time`, `requiredBy`, `dateReason`, `oneOff`, `url`, `browserDevice`, `jsessionid`, `customersProducts`, `investigationsUndertaken`, `whatquestions`, `supportingInformation`, `open`
```

I am quite new to trying to nest a query and I am trying to select all records in my incidents table where the title or status match a keyword and then I only want the results which occur between a selected timestamp range. Both the individual queries here work on their own and return results but when I try and nest them I get the error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s). What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `incidents`
WHERE
     `timestamp` BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-23 23:59:59'  
IN
(SELECT * FROM `incidents` WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' OR `status` LIKE '%test%')
```

Ideally I want to return all fields, hence the use of *, where it's between my timestamp range and the status or title contain a keyword I specify. In the example query above I have used the keyword 'test'.

Comment: Instead of the sub-query using `SELECT *` you should specifically be selecting the timestamp column (or whichever column is relevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a subquery, it's generally expected that you will provide an index column for the main query to return from. You cannot return `SELECT *` because there's no implicit column to key off of. I picked `index` (hopefully that's actually an index)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `incidents`
WHERE
     `timestamp` BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-23 23:59:59'  
AND index IN
(SELECT index FROM `incidents` WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' OR `status` LIKE '%test%')
```

Comment: It is also quite pointless to use a subquery for that. You can just move the inner query where clause to the outer one.